# Output of console.log in React Native

Tags: debugging, react-native, styles

Is it possible to debug styles at react-native in a screen for example?

`console.log(styles.buttonBackground)// returns 140
 console.log(styles.button.backgroundColor)// undefined`

while it has background. I use all standard things of react-native.
style is defined, debugger works well. but I'm unable to get the value of styles in debug.

Comment: if you are looking for debug the styles you can use Show Inpector option in debugger and check your style, if not can you please tell me what you are going to achive or some more code sample would be good to help you..

Comment: @nish, I have a dynamic style with a lot of inherit, sometimes I see strange behaves, for those situations I wanna see the exact value of the items in styles.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using [`react-devtools`](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/tree/master/packages/react-devtools).

It synchronizes the `inspector` of the `react-native` with its `debug tool` to get the values of the `react-dom elements`.

The relevant details are mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/tree/master/packages/react-devtools#integration-with-react-native-inspector)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you would like to debug Redux as well, try out [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger)

I've written a [guide](https://medium.com/@tetsuyahasegawa/how-to-integrate-react-native-debugger-to-your-expo-react-native-project-db1d631fad02) on how to set it up with Expo.